# how to remove black transparent color from dialog fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have tried following codes.

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

But nothing helps.

[image: remove black transparent color from dialog fragment]

Helps will be appreciated. thank you.

[image: now the image looks like below image]

[image: need resend otp also transparent]

need resend otp also transparent. but the dialog size , background color is ok.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrOtpContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter OTP"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtFirstOtp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:ems="1"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtSecondOtp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:textSize="25sp"

                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:ems="1"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtThirdOtp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:ems="1"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtFourthOtp"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:ems="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnResendOtp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lnrOtpContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Resend OTP"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Dialog fragment with adjustable size is needed. now background black color problem resolved by the help of other developers.

Comment: Did you tried this , dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

Comment: no. give me a second i will give try

Comment: check now. now the dialog went like this.

Comment: Is that ok for you?

Comment: no. it's not. i need like third image. I will post it now.

Comment: post your xml..

Comment: updated with xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
mProgressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Dialog fragment with adjustable size,then you need to change all width and height to wrap_content.

If you have still same issue.then you shouls try multiple screen support methodology of android.

Here is ref.:

[Multiple screen support.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)